# how to prevent access database and resources in laravel blade?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to create a shop builder that the user can create own theme and upload it to my host. and now I want to prevent users cant access database and model and resources in blade.

Because they can write malicious code through the blade on my server and cause system crashes.

I want to send only a list of variables for each blade's page that contains the values ​​they need on this page and users can only use these variables and can not access my server database or resources and my files server.
I had to prevent user cant access database in the blade

Anyone have an idea for this؟

thank you

Comment: If you get all datas before the view rendering, maybe closing the Database connection will do what you want `DB::disconnect('foo');` 
 https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#accessing-connections

Comment: Your question is _stricte_ opinion-based and doesn't fit StackOverflow's requirements. I'm afraid it will be closed soon.

Comment: If I disconnect the database after receiving the information. Can't users reconnect via blade and php?

Comment: blade can contain PHP blocks so you are not going to be restricting anything ... maybe something like Twig with sandboxing might work

Answer (score 0):

I have a need similar to yours

after several experiments and attempts I have found a solution that might work,
but with limitations/restrictions

it would be appropriate "from my point of view" to think about introducing another way to render your content.

in the face of my research I have found 2 possible solutions

- introduce [liquid](https://github.com/jooorooo/laravel-liquid)

  - PRO

    - no type of access to the code
  - AGAINST

    - everything that will be accessible must be processed in advance
- introduce [TWIG](https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge)

  - PRO

    - you do not have default access to eloquent or anything else that has not been passed to it
    - you can pass an 'object' intended as a php class with all its methods and properties
  - AGAINST

    - just because you can pass 'objects' you may come across the unpleasant condition that an object brings with it something that the view should not have access to

### conclusions

in conclusion, 'my' choice was liquid, since it guaranteed me more security, in addition to other companies such as shopify have decided to use it also for this peculiarity